# Hardware support on amd's ryzen based models

Tags: drivers

If everything works well on ubuntu with laptops which is based on amd's ryzen overall?

Answer (score 0):

AMD Ryzen compatibility with Ubuntu is pretty good, but check the Ryzen CPU's specifications before buying a Ryzen processor. Some Ryzen processors have no integrated graphics, so they can't run Ubuntu unless there is an additional discrete graphics processor installed.